# Cannot disable trigger on {table} as the target is not in the current database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I was trying to disable all triggers on a SQL Server table to delete some rows, then wanted to enable the triggers back on.

But disable triggers command is causing an error.

Command:

```
DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON [PTS].[dbo].[cadResources]
```

Error

> Cannot disable trigger on 'PTS.dbo.cadResources' as the target is not in the current database.

Comment: What about the error do you need help with? Seems pretty clear...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do

```
USE [PTS]
DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON [dbo].[cadResources]
```

Comment: It is a limitation, as for why exactly they did it this way - hard to tell, should be investigated more deeply - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#trigger-limitations